# Java Threads Synchronizing Problem

Tags: java

I have the following 2 classes code that produce this result for instance:

```
Wainting for calculation to complete...
Calculator thread says HELLO!
T1 says that total is 10
Wainting for calculation to complete...
Wainting for calculation to complete...
```

Now threads are waiting but nobody is going to notify them.
How can I force the threads from T1 to T3 to run before the "Calculator thread" wake em up?

```
public class Calculator implements Runnable{

  private int total;

  public int getTotal() {
    return total;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    synchronized (this) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            total += i;
        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " says HELLO!");
        notifyAll();
    }
  }
}


import static java.lang.System.out;

public class Reader implements Runnable{

  private Calculator c;


  public Reader(Calculator calc) {
    c = calc;
  }

  public Calculator getCalculator() {
    return c;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Calculator calc = new Calculator();
    Reader read = new Reader(calc);

    Thread thread1 = new Thread(read);
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(read);
    Thread thread3 = new Thread(read);

    thread1.setName("T1");
    thread2.setName("T2");
    thread3.setName("T3");

    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();
    thread3.start();

    Thread calcThread = new Thread(read.getCalculator());
    calcThread.setName("Calculator thread");
    calcThread.start();
  }
}


  @Override
  public void run() {
      synchronized (c) {
          try {
              out.println("Wainting for calculation to complete...");
              c.wait();
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " says that " + "total is "  + c.getTotal());
      }

  }

}
```

Comment: I can add Thread.sleep() after the thread3.start() but i consider that is not an appropriate solution.

Comment: You should never use wait/notify, but rather use the debugged utilities from java.util.concurrent and completely redesign your application accordingly.  It's not clear what your real application is, so I can't really tell you what you should be using.

Comment: @toto : There is no reason why you shouldnt use wait/notify. They are simple and elagent primitives. java.util.concurrent classes are just wrappers over the same. I agree higher level constructs such as read and write locks, barriers and latches are offered by these classes.. but you should never really use an anvil when a simple hammer would suffice.

Comment: @arun_suresh I see it backward: the simple hammer are the utilities in java.util.concurrent and the anvil are the low-level constructs (wait/notify).  In "Java Concurrency in Practice" (which is an excellent book written by the designers of Java), they only talk about wait/notify at the complete end of the book and it's used to build custom synchronization libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thread.join() may seem like an option in this particular situation. Since you have control of the `main()` function and you know exactly when each thread is starting.

A more general way to handle this situation is use a conditional variable and call the `c.wait()` within a loop to check the condition variable.

Basically add the `isFinished` field in the `Calculator` class :

```
public class Calculator implements Runnable {
...
  public volatile boolean isFinished = false
..
..
```

Then you replace `c.wait()` with :

```
...
while (!c.isFinished) {
  c.wait();
}
...
```

Finally in the `run() method of your Calculator class after calculating total, set the isFinished field

```
....
 for(int i = 0; ....
     total = += i;
 }
 c.isFinished = true
....
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad! It helps :) This is a nice simple solution.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I would write the code.  Rather than trying to re-invent the wheel with wait/notify I would use concurrency library to do what is needed, a Future.

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Main {
    static final long start = System.nanoTime();

    static void log(String text) {
        double seconds = (System.nanoTime() - start) / 1e9;
        System.out.printf("%s %.6f - %s%n", Thread.currentThread().getName(), seconds, text);
    }

    static class Calculator implements Callable<Integer> {
        @Override
        public Integer call() throws Exception {
            int total = 0;
            log("calculating total");
            for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++)
                total += i;
            log("total is " + total);
            return total;
        }
    }

    static class Reader implements Callable<Void> {
        private final Future<Integer> totalFuture;

        public Reader(Future<Integer> totalFuture) {
            this.totalFuture = totalFuture;
        }

        @Override
        public Void call() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
            log("Waiting for total.");
            int total = totalFuture.get();
            log("... got total= " + total);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        Future<Integer> totalFuture = es.submit(new Calculator());
        es.submit(new Reader(totalFuture));
        es.submit(new Reader(totalFuture));
        es.submit(new Reader(totalFuture));
        es.shutdown();
    }
}
```

prints

```
pool-1-thread-1 0.008154 - calculating total
pool-1-thread-4 0.011356 - Waiting for total.
pool-1-thread-3 0.011292 - Waiting for total.
pool-1-thread-2 0.011128 - Waiting for total.
pool-1-thread-1 0.025097 - total is 1249975000
pool-1-thread-4 0.025351 - ... got total= 1249975000
pool-1-thread-3 0.025372 - ... got total= 1249975000
pool-1-thread-2 0.025380 - ... got total= 1249975000
```

---

After

```
thread3.start();
```

add the following to wait for the threads to finish.

```
thread1.join();
thread2.join();
thread3.join();
```

Comment: I edited the code. I have deleted some rolls by mistake. 
If I add this code the threads are really waiting to complete and the program never reaches the calcThread.start(); witch invokes the notifyAll() method... So the program never ends. 
Any other suggestions ?

Comment: The problem is that I would remove all the code which is not needed until you have just one loop to calculate the total and one print statement. Everything else doesn't really do anything.

Comment: This is a principal question. Don't take in mind what the code is actually doing (I know it is pointless). I just wanted to know how can I make the threads to run one after another and then wait altogether until the notifyAll() came because I thought that is why I made them synchronized.

Comment: Have al look at the code using Future.  You can also implement Future yourself using synchronized/wait/notifyAll.

Comment: Thanks! This looks like a good result. But I am not familiar with the concurrent library and with this Callable interface. I will read about it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

U may use `Thread.join()` method.. I'm not sure how abouts of good programming practices but that will work..

Comment: See the comment I left on Peter Lawrey using the join()